# "can't allocate region" error when running app

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't even run the app on my ipod Touch 5g that it crashes after 10 seconds giving this error:

```
2013-02-18 18:49:57.518 Splash-it[1340:907] Error: HTTP status code: 200
Splash-it(1340,0x453d000) malloc: *** mmap(size=516096) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The app is an both ipad and iphone app, but on the ipad it runs fine.

Sometimes I also get this error:

```
0x1c41e8:  str.w  r10, [r0, #72]
```

What does all of this mean? I run my app on Instruments, and I can see that the bites are constantly growing, but I can't understand what is causing it...

Comment: do you suggest separating, and making 2 separate apps, 1 for iphone, and 1 for iPad?

Comment: Are you using any c or c++ in your code?? Are you trying to create an array with a large capacity ?? by accidently or even knowingly??

Comment: no, not really. I solved the problem by selecting all the options in the diagnostics menu of Xcode (logging, memory management). Do you think this could do?